# ASp.net Web Application Connection string issue

Tags: iis, webforms, iis-7, connection-string, windows-server-2003

I have a old application and the other developer was using connection string like this

```
  <add key="test" value="Data Source=Serzero;Database=NijaDatabase;trusted_connection=true;Connect Timeout=360"/>
```

My question is that the application is ruining perfectly on the local server access remote database when i am using VS2010 but when i am hosting this my application on the IIS on my machine getting error ...Locally applicaiton working fine login logout everything but on IIS getting this error when try to log in

```
Login failed for user
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user .

Source Error:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either add `Integrated Security=False;User Id=userid;Password=password` to your connection string.

Comment: Nop getting same error if i put Integrated Security=False; it show my username and say same thing and if i put username same thing :(

Comment: Does your user account have access to the database? that needs to be whatever user account is being used to access the database. Also, maybe check to make sure Anonymous Authentication is set to off in IIS.

Comment: When i am adding Anonymous Authentication off getting this error on the load of the application  HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

Comment: Hmmm, i'm not sure then. Even with Anonymous Authentication enabled, if you have the connection string set-up correctly with the User ID and Password, it should work fine.

Comment: i did some changes in advance setting of the Application pool in iis  Process model and identity local service some how know it is showing me throw connection string error that me know the problem is for the authentication i guess